# Correct usage of the phrase "which, in turn."

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, sentence-structure, phrases

His empire created the foundation for the Roman Republic and the Roman Empire, which in turn, had their own great works.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for your first question on ELL. Since you're new I'd like to offer the suggestion that you add more detail to your question. Right now it's not clear what you're asking. There's only one sentence here and we can't tell what you want to know about it. The title should be a summary of your question and the body should explain what you're asking and why you want to know, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your sentence is *syntactically* sound, it's not entirely *semantically* sound. You can use *which, in turn* here, but the existing construction is missing a parallel component.

It would sound better with an additional piece and some slight reprhasing:

> His empire created the foundation for the Roman Republic, *which had some great works*, and later the Roman Empire, *which, in turn, had its own great works*.

Otherwise, a different parallel meaning would make effective use of the phrase:

> His empire *created the foundation for the Roman Republic,* which, in turn, *created the foundation for the Roman Empire*.

---

Alternatively, if I'm parsing your meaning incorrectly—and you mean *the Roman Republic and the Roman Empire* to be a single thing, rather than one thing that led to the other, then you could use the following:

> His empire, *which had some great works*, created the foundation for the Roman Republic and the Roman Empire, *which, in turn, had its own great works.*

But again, this involves a parallel structure—here, one thing having great works followed by another thing having great works—that is missing from the original sentence.

Comment: Thanks a lot! (I meant the second one)